# Safetynet API helper error

Tags: android, google-api, android-security, safetynet

I wanted to implement safety net API to verify the device status one of the easiest methods I found is a safety net helper class which makes the implementation so simple github.com/scottyab/safetynethelper.
I copied all the class from safetynetlib and added them to my code. I followed the method for implantation but I get an error
code 
 
`final SafetyNetHelper safetyNetHelper = new SafetyNetHelper(BuildConfig.API1);`

```
public boolean safetynet()
    {
        safetyNetHelper.requestTest(getApplicationContext(), new SafetyNetHelper.SafetyNetWrapperCallback() {
            @Override
            public void error(int errorCode, String msg) {
            //handle and retry depending on errorCode
        }
        @Override
        public void success(boolean ctsProfileMatch) {
            if(ctsProfileMatch){
                safetynet=true;
            }else{
               safetynet=false;
            }
        }
    });
    return safetynet;
  }`
```

> 04-20 22:32:50.950 28741-28741/com.aashish.smart D/SafetyNetHelper: apkDigest:IQUb5ULuwdbqOwpQn3jZev2EGXcjtk/yGYUvk1c64F8=
>   04-20 22:32:51.028 28741-28741/com.aashish.smart V/SafetyNetHelper: Google play services connected
>   04-20 22:32:51.028 28741-28741/com.aashish.smart V/SafetyNetHelper: running SafetyNet.API Test
>   04-20 22:32:54.499 28741-28741/com.aashish.smart D/SafetyNetResponse: decodedJWTPayload json:{"nonce":"tnd1YpjORIX4teJEd7LuigDWNhWkF6s4T7Ay811BxsM=","timestampMs":1461171774655,"apkPackageName":"com.aashish.smart","apkDigestSha256":"IQUb5ULuwdbqOwpQn3jZev2EGXcjtk/yGYUvk1c64F8=","ctsProfileMatch":true,"extension":"CQ6MIM+qMkMv","apkCertificateDigestSha256":["PHKalK4AF5EmDbPL5eBQS9EZJVPkgp06cr64rVQ7B7w="]}
>   04-20 22:32:54.500 28741-28741/com.aashish.smart E/SafetyNetHelper: invalid apkCertificateDigest, local/expected = [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>IG6eWNkmNZYXuEj14nqWrSM+AniDcW3U/NwROXOERZfvtBiiwuy0Oc8GG31VmYAd6jgdkfsXfd+96wZxqH8PRtq3m1tjXYGb9Kg1CM1oDdN5H6xtqjU24nSpQEWWs6THuWHA1LEsAnnO0JM3lm0ltBOuIGJtWBd5S6tHMgi4U+m1z/oJAW0HAyWwbuwy7/YP1uEKlEEM669bUYG6iQ4dE3cIB5guZF2qMjwPKscW9bRjoviTgJUGmmVRdpd1Dk/OOZFUEK4A+ii5c7SLW2e//QoN3WV30zNHJArCvFfTGRbeZpwOl4Z4=]
>   04-20 22:32:54.500 28741-28741/com.aashish.smart E/SafetyNetHelper: invalid apkCertificateDigest, response = [PHKalK4AF5EmDbPL5eBQS9EZJVPkgp06cr64rVQ7B7w=]
>   04-20 22:32:54.657 28741-4205/com.aashish.smart E/AndroidDeviceVerifier: problem validating JWS Message :https://www.googleapis.com/androidcheck/v1/attestations/verify?key=A....................................0
>                                                                           java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.googleapis.com/androidcheck/v1/attestations/verify?key=A.....................................0
>                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
>                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
>                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>                                                                               at com.aashish.smart.AndroidDeviceVerifier$AndroidDeviceVerifierTask.doInBackground(AndroidDeviceVerifier.java:113)
>                                                                               at com.aashish.smart.AndroidDeviceVerifier$AndroidDeviceVerifierTask.doInBackground(AndroidDeviceVerifier.java:82)
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

full log : pastebin(dot)com/YXkS7NgW 
can someone help me to find out what the error is I am not able to find. or is there any other tutorial out there for me to work on safety net API

Answer (score 0):

I'm also researching solution for this and currently I have resolved the "FileNotFoundException" for the URL hit .

Resolution:
You should create a project on Google API console if you don't have one and enable Android Device Verification API.

Create "Server Key" and leave IP field blank to be able to connect from mobile application.

That will do it (:

I'm still working on how to resolve apkCertificateDigest mismatch issue